# php get all content from stream

Tags: php, stream

I want to read information from stream, for example I try to connect to munin-node, send request and read all data that remote socket(munin) will send for me

```
$stream = stream_socket_client('tcp://127.0.0.1:4949', $errorNumber, $errorMessage);
stream_socket_sendto($stream, "list\n");
$content = stream_get_contents($stream, -1);
print_r($content);
```

but, stream_get_contents read data.... and blocked! The code continue working only after stream timeout will be over.
Any body know how I need change code to get answer  from server with out blocking?

Answer (score 0):

You are supposed to specify how many bytes you are waiting for in the second arg of stream_get_content. But maybe you dont know that. At least, here, you know that you gonna get two lines. So you could use this work around, calling fgets twice :

```
$fp = fsockopen("localhost", 4949, $errno, $errstr, 30);
if (!$fp) {
    echo "$errstr ($errno)\n";
} else {
    fwrite($fp, "list\n");
    echo fgets($fp, 1024);
    echo fgets($fp, 1024);
    fclose($fp);
}
```

If you want to do it your way you should have a look on socket_set_blocking(0). And/or use stream_get_meta_data() to know how many bytes you'll get from the stream

Comment: use fgets not a good solution, because answer can contain N count of lines. The second what about not a '\n' delimiters on responses. Benchmarks of stream_get_line very better than fgets. stream_set_blocking is for writing or I not understood. I need flexibile solution for my task and I want to use php5+ methods, because they are more faster